# PySide custom Tab

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I am using a QTabWidget with multiple tabs.  I want to create a tab which is different (has a different styling then the rest of the tabs).  For instance how firefox has the green plus button to add a new tab that is different from the other tabs.

I was looking through documentation and could not find anything related to the unique styling of a tab. I looked at QTabWidget and QTabBar but no luck.

This is how I am creating tabs

```
self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget()
self.tabWidget.addTab(QtGui.QWidget, "Tab_1")
```

Is there something I have overlooked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, Qt has really good documentation with very good examples, all [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar). [Main page to stylesheets.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html)

All you have to do is to set the stylesheet either with `QtDesigner` or in python itself, like this:

```
self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                    "border:1px solid rgb(255, 170, 255);")
```

Here is a sample stylesheet (the third example from `Qtabwidget`)

```
 QTabWidget::pane { /* The tab widget frame */
     border-top: 2px solid #C2C7CB;
     position: absolute;
     top: -0.5em;
 }

 QTabWidget::tab-bar {
     alignment: center;
 }

 /* Style the tab using the tab sub-control. Note that
     it reads QTabBar _not_ QTabWidget */
 QTabBar::tab {
     background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                 stop: 0 #E1E1E1, stop: 0.4 #DDDDDD,
                                 stop: 0.5 #D8D8D8, stop: 1.0 #D3D3D3);
     border: 2px solid #C4C4C3;
     border-bottom-color: #C2C7CB; /* same as the pane color */
     border-top-left-radius: 4px;
     border-top-right-radius: 4px;
     min-width: 8ex;
     padding: 2px;
 }

 QTabBar::tab:selected, QTabBar::tab:hover {
     background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                 stop: 0 #fafafa, stop: 0.4 #f4f4f4,
                                 stop: 0.5 #e7e7e7, stop: 1.0 #fafafa);
 }

 QTabBar::tab:selected {
     border-color: #9B9B9B;
     border-bottom-color: #C2C7CB; /* same as pane color */
 }
```

Comment: Right, I realized that, but using that ALL the tabs will be exactly the same.  Each tab will have the same style sheet. What if I have 5 tabs, and I want one two have a completely different style sheet then the other (NOT counting selected/hovered tabs).

Comment: Have you looked at something like this `QTabBar::tab:first` as a selector?

Comment: Aha! Sorry, that was dumb of me.  That solved it.  Thank you very much :)